# What is an efficient way to get e.g. a specific member of a class by its id in C++?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I need help understanding how I setup my programme correctly. I have a class that stores "Customers". I read those customers from a file into the programme as class members. Now at a different part of my programme I want to get the corresponding data of the customer (e.g.: age, city) by the customers unique id.

```cpp
class Customers {
       const int customerid;
       std::string name;
       int age;
       std::string city;
}
```

How can I get access to my class member where customerid = 3?

Right now I was successful putting all the data from my file into an std::vector and by searching the std::vector with find_if. Is there an easier way to archive this?

I remember from php that I was just simply using a multi-array, where the key was the unique customerid.

```php
$customers= array (
  1=>array("name"=>"John", "age"=> 22, "city" > "New York"),
  2=>array("name"=>"Peter", "age"=> 58, "city" > "London"),
  3=>array("name"=>"Jason", "age"=> 25, "city" > "Melbourne")
);
```

I got my relevant information, for example the city of customerid = 3, this way:

```php
echo $customers[3]["city"];
```

So what is the best way to do this in C++?

Comment: `std::map`, but that (similarly to your PHP example) will store ID separately from the object.

Comment: Are the `customerid`s always consecutive, and do they start at 0?

Comment: Your answer probably depends on your target.  On a desktop with a 'relaxed' startup time, the initial data load time of the data base is possibly less important.  On one  embedded system with some real-time constraints, I have been very impressed by the performance of a database.

Comment: Question aside, `const int customerid;` may be problematic in the future. `const` members make the type non-assignable and should usually be avoided. As an alternative way of preserving the invariance, consider making `customerid` a `private` non-`const` member instead, and providing a `public` getter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) will store customers in such a way (usually balanced binary search tree) that you can add and retrieve in logarithmic time.

This has an advantage over `std::map` in that you do not need to separate the key (customer id) from the value (the customer).

We have to do a little boilerplate to allow comparison of `int` to `Customer` (and vice-versa) by declaring a `is_transparent` type in our comparison class for the set (C++14):

```
static int id_counter = 0;

struct Customer {
       const int customerid = id_counter++;
       std::string name = std::to_string(customerid);
       int age{};
       std::string city;
};

struct customer_comp
{
    bool operator()(const Customer& lhs, const Customer& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.customerid < rhs.customerid;
    }

    bool operator()(int id, const Customer& rhs) const
    {
        return id < rhs.customerid;
    }

    bool operator()(const Customer& lhs, int id) const
    {
        return lhs.customerid < id;
    }

    using is_transparent = bool; // so that we can compare int to Customer
};
```

This is so that we can do something like `customers.find(1)->city`.

And now you can use both to create your collection like so:

```
int main()
{
    std::set<Customer, customer_comp> customers;
    customers.insert(Customer{});
    customers.insert(Customer{});

    for(const auto& c : customers)
        std::cout << c.customerid << std::endl;
}
```

#### [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fv7drrsv5)

---

You may also consider [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) that behaves similarly, although the underlying storage is a hash table, and your comparison struct will compare `==` instead of `<`. This has the further benefit of constant expected time insert and retrieval (although it may or may not actually be faster than `std::set` in practice).

---

#### Aside:

The representation of `std::set` I think is closest to a "real world" scenario where you'd use a database as a backing store. A database index (or often table as index) is implemented as a balanced tree of degree N (N is specific to implementation/tuning), and a balanced binary search tree is one example of such a tree. In reality the B Trees used by a database have a much higher branching factor.

Comment: I would add that you would use [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) (like `customers.find(3)->city`, with checks for end iterator) to lookup by id

Comment: @Martumbo: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare 
Regarding the creation of a customer without entering an ID manually... you will need a constructor for that. there is a lot of debate on the best way to handle construction of an object that needs a lot of parameters; the most straightforward way is to simply require them all as parameters.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks. Where can I read up on what the bool operators do in this case. I'm puzzled because they do not seem to be used in the remaining code and because there is no "==" or "<" behind <operator>.
Also, how can I insert a new customer without needing to enter an ID manually? This one only works when I put the <const int customerid> in the struct last:   
`````
customers.insert(Customer{"John", 23,"London"});
````
I guess I would need to create a constructer but that seems like taking a detour in case I have a lot of data in the Customers struct.

Comment: @AndyG your answer overlapped with my comment which I deleted since I couldn't edit it anymore while trying to format it properly. I will check the link out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
struct CustomerData {
   std::string name;
   int age = -1;
   std::string city;
};
```

these are the attributes of a customer.

```
std::unordered_map< int, CustomerData > customersData = {
  {1, {"John", 22, "New York}},
  {2, {"Peter", 58, "London}}
};
```

Above we have a map (unordered, because we don't care about order) from the int id to the data.  The initialization looks a lot like python you may note.

Another way to add data to the map:

```
customersData[3] = {"Jason", 25, "Melborne"};
```

there are other ways.

Here we look up the id 3:

```
if (customersData.count(3) != 0) {
  auto data = customersData[3];
  std::cout << "Customer #3 is " << data.name << " age " << data.age << " from " << data.city << "\n";
}
```

you can also iterate:

```
for (auto[ id, data ] : customersData) {
  std::cout << "Customer #" << id << " is " << data.name << " age " << data.age << " from " << data.city << "\n";
}
```

this being C++, there are small changes you can make to reduce overhead at a few spots, but it also makes the code more complex.  I kept it simple.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use a `std::map<int, Customers>` instead of the vector. This way, you can search the map by calling `find` ([example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)).

If the map gets bigger over time, you should consider switching to an `std::unordered_map` or maybe even to a database, instead of the file access (something like SQLite). This way, you use SQL-statements to filter by id, which is faster then loading and searching everything locally.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as Yksisarvinen told you, a `std::map` could be a good option, or even just `std::unordered_map<int, Customer>` because I think any Customer is as important as any other.

If you have all of them in a file, you have to search them and figure out how are they stored, I don't think that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can think something similar. You can make in memory database of your Customers class for each object in tuple and map it with key(id) from std::map or std::unordered_map container so you can later query it efficiently.

```
class Customers {
public:
using CustomerInfo = std::tuple<std::string,int,std::string>;
Customers(const int id, std::string name, int age,std::string city):customerid(id),name(name),age(age),city(city){
¦   m_custInfo.emplace(id,std::make_tuple(name,age,city));
}
std::optional<CustomerInfo>QueryCustomer(const int id){
¦   auto it = m_custInfo.find(id);
¦   if(it!=m_custInfo.end()){
¦   ¦   return it->second;
¦   }
¦   return {}; // same as std::nullopt; 
}
private:
std::map<int, CustomerInfo> m_custInfo;
const int customerid;
std::string name;
int age;
std::string city;
```

};
int main() {

```
Customers cust(101, "Joy", 13, "Tokyo");
const auto ret = cust.QueryCustomer(101);
if (ret) {
auto[name, age, city] = *ret;
std::cout << std::endl
          << name << " " << age << " " << city;
```

}

return 1;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::map<int,CustomerData>` either ordered or unordered map, depending on your need.

you can use `map[customerid]` to get the corresponding object. It's like caching the data in memory.